# Sequlize combining has many association in single field

Tags: graphql, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript, graphql-sequelize

For the project I'm working on a player has multiple games. But these are always needed in a combined way.

So I was wondering on how i could make it so I can place it in my graphql scheme as a signle item called `games`.

I've did something similar for the `fullName` but I couldn't find a way to make a combined association

```js
@Table({
  timestamps: true
})
export class Player extends Model<Player> {

  @Column({ unique: 'compositeIndex' })
  firstName: string;

  @Column({ unique: 'compositeIndex' })
  lastName: string;

  @Column({ unique: 'compositeIndex' })
  memberId: string;

  // Assicioations
  @HasMany(() => Game, { as: 'player1-team1', foreignKey: 'player1Team1Id' })
  games1?: Game[];
  @HasMany(() => Game, { as: 'player1-team2', foreignKey: 'player1Team2Id' })
  games2?: Game[];
  @HasMany(() => Game, { as: 'player2-team1', foreignKey: 'player2Team1Id' })
  games3?: Game[];
  @HasMany(() => Game, { as: 'player2-team2', foreignKey: 'player2Team2Id' })
  games4?: Game[];

  @Column(DataType.VIRTUAL(DataType.STRING, ['firstName', 'lastName']))
  get fullName(this: Player): string {
    return `${this.firstName || ''} ${this.lastName || ''}`.trim();
  }

  get games() {
    return [...this.games1, ...this.games2, ...this.games3, ...this.games4];
  }
}
```

Current Scheme object

```js
  const playerType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Player',
    description: 'A Player',
    fields: Object.assign(attributeFields(sequelizeInstance.models.Player), {
      games: {
        type: new GraphQLList(gameType),
        resolve: resolver(/* Some magic here? */),
      }
    })
  });

  return new GraphQLSchema({
    query: new GraphQLObjectType({
      name: 'RootQueryType',
      fields: {
        player: {
          type: playerType,
          args: {
            id: {
              description: 'id of the user',
              type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)
            }
          },
          resolve: resolver(Player)
        }
      }
    })
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a 'solution' to my problem
I've made the "error" that I've made 4 foreign keys. by creating a many to many releation i was able to get everything working as I wanted to.

But I'm still  curious on how one would do this ...